# How to add two images to one slide in python pptx

Tags: python, image, addition, python-pptx

I am trying to paste two pictures into a powerpoint slide on after another. However, whenever I am not sure how to do this. I know how to add one picture, but can't find anything online for adding two.

To add a picture I do the code below

```
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img_path, left, top, width = Inches(7.72), height = Inches(4.5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `add_picture` with a different set of coordinates so that the pictures don't overlap, [as in the official documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#add-picture-example).