# how to add two or more images to the same slide in for loop python-pptx

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm trying to add images into one slide using python pptx package.

[How to add two images to one slide in python pptx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046827/how-to-add-two-images-to-one-slide-in-python-pptx)

But I have difficulties with when I do this in a for loop;

let's say we have a bunch of pictures in the directory and we want to resize and add the current slide as we go along with the pictures in directory. When I have `eagle` or `hawk` in the directory resize & position them and put them into current slide and move the next one!

What I am getting is that each picture in different slides;

Here is my code look like;

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx.util import Inches

img_path = 'r/D/test'

eagle_1.png, eagle_2.png .... eagle_5.png

hawk_1.png, hawk_2.png .... hawk_5.png


def ppt_generator(img_path):

    prs = Presentation()
    blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
    #slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

    for images in glob.glob(img_path + '/*.png'):


        if 'eagle' in str(images):
            slide = prs.slides.add_slide(content_slide_layout)   
            slide = slide.shapes.add_picture(images , left=Inches(0), top=Inches(0), width=Inches(3), height = Inches(3))

        if 'hawk' in str(images):
            slide = prs.slides.add_slide(content_slide_layout)   
            slide = slide.shapes.add_picture(images , left=Inches(2), top=Inches(2), width=Inches(3), height = Inches(3))

    prs.save('eagle_hawk.pptx')
```

What I want to have is that for each eagle_1 and hawk_1 should be in the same slide and so on!

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to assemble eagle/hawk picture pairs in a separate function. Maybe something like:

```
def iter_image_pairs():
    eagles, hawks = [], []
    for image_path in glob.glob(img_path + '/*.png'):
        if "eagle" in image_path:
            eagles.append(image_path)
        elif "hawk" in image_path:
            hawks.append(image_path)
    for pair in zip(eagles, hawks):
        yield pair
```

Then your slide loop can just become:

```
for eagle, hawk in iter_image_pairs():
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(content_slide_layout)   
    slide.shapes.add_picture(
        eagle, left=Inches(0), top=Inches(0), width=Inches(3), height=Inches(3)
    )
    slide.shapes.add_picture(
        hawk, left=Inches(2), top=Inches(2), width=Inches(3), height=Inches(3)
    )
```