# pairing one picture to multiple pictures in folder

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, python-pptx

I have some pictures in the folder I want to pair so I can add them to my slide with iterative fashion. I want to pair pictures ending with `mp` ones to `bp` ones. One caveat is that there are multiple pictures ending with `bp` and `bp` so that adding logical check would be feasible.

lets say we have a pictures in the folder

[image]

I want to pair `1_birds_bp.png` to other pictures starting with `1` and ending with `mp`

so that the pair should look like #expected result

```
('D:\\test\\1_birds_bp.png', 'D:\\test\\1_eagle_mp.png')
('D:\\test\\1_birds_bp.png', 'D:\\test\\1_hawk_mp.png')
('D:\\test\\1_birds_bp.png', 'D:\\test\\1_owl_mp.png')
```

and for `reptile` group

```
('D:\\test\\2_reptile_bp.png', 'D:\\test\\2_crocodile_mp.png')
('D:\\test\\2_reptile_bp.png', 'D:\\test\\2_snake_mp.png')
```

So by following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977855/how-to-add-two-or-more-images-to-the-same-slide-in-for-loop-python-pptx) 
I tried

```
def image_pairs(folder):
    bp, mp = [], []

    for image_path in glob.glob(folder + '/*.png'):
        if "bp" in image_path:
            bp.append(image_path)

        elif "mp" in image_path:
            mp.append(image_path)
    for pair in zip(bp, mp):
        print(pair)
        #yield pair
```

but I can pair the only

```
('D:\\test\\1_birds_bp.png', 'D:\\test\\1_eagle_mp.png')
('D:\\test\\2_reptile_bp.png', 'D:\\test\\1_hawk_mp.png')
```

how can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check all combinations and pick the ones that match:

```
from itertools import combinations
from pathlib import Path
files = Path(folder).glob('*.png')
list_of_pairs = [(a, b) for a, b in combinations(files, 2)
                 if (a.name.startswith(b.name[0]) and (('mp' in a.name and 'bp' in b.name) or ('bp' in a.name and 'mp' in b.name))]
```

Even better, use `filter` on `itertools.combinations` for custom pairwise checks.

Comment: Thanks for your solution it worked very well. Although it looks like medium leetcode question:)

Answer (score 1):

I like @xletmjm's approach, although `pathlib` is only available in Python >= 3.4.

Here's an alternate approach that works with what you've used so far.

```
import glob

class Path(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self._path = path

    @property
    def stem(self):
        """The "base" part of the filename, without the extension."""
        return ".".join(self.filename.split(".")[:-1])

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self._path.split("/")[-1]

    @property
    def filename_prefix(self):
        return self.stem.split("_")[0]

    @property
    def filename_suffix(self):
        return self.stem.split("_")[-1]

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path


def iter_bp_paths(paths):
    """Generate each Path object in `paths` with filename having "_bp" suffix."""
    return (p for p in paths if p.filename_suffix == "bp")


def iter_mp_paths(paths, prefix):
    """Generate each Path object in `paths` with `prefix` and "mp" suffix."""
    return (
        p for p in paths if p.filename_prefix == prefix and p.filename_suffix == "mp"
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    paths = [Path(path) for path in glob.glob("/Users/you/tmp/*.png")]
    for bp_path in iter_bp_paths(paths):
        for mp_path in iter_mp_paths(paths, bp_path.filename_prefix):
            print(bp_path.path, mp_path.path)
```

Comment: One can use `os.listdir()` in place of `Path.iterdir()`.